# XPath to find sibling attribute based on sibling condition

Tags: xpath

I want to find the postal code based on  AddressID in my XML.

```xml
<Address City="Londong" County="Greater London" FlatNumber="" HouseNumber="702" PostCode="EH14 3HW" Street="" AddressID="0" isPrimary="1"/>
<Address City="Braintree" County="Essex" FlatNumber="" HouseNumber="586" PostCode="CM79AB" Street="Blocking End" AddressID="1"  isPrimary="0"/>
```

I'm trying different XPath statements and not getting a value or getting null. I'm trying to say, Give me the PostCode where the AddressID = 1.

I've tried the following:

```xml
//Address[AddressID = 1]@PostCode
//Address[AddressID = 1]/@PostCode
//Address[AddressID = 1 @PostCode]
```

Comment: FYI -- if something isn't intended to be runnable in a browser, use "code samples", not "code snippets". Code samples are accessible with the `{}` editor widget.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with which one to use. That helps.

Comment: BTW, usually when folks talk about siblings in XML it's in reference to elements next to each other; attributes hanging off the same element don't actually have a defined ordering, so a lot of sibling-related semantics (following-sibling, preceding-sibling, etc) don't apply.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not brand new to XML, but trying to remember the exact words. I know different online communities are exacting so I'm doing my best to be exact. XML is very picky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AddressID is an attribute (same as the PostCode), so you need to use a `@` for both.

```
//Address[@AddressID="1"]/@PostCode
```

---

The query you were trying, `//Address[AddressID = 1]/@PostCode`, looks for something like this:

```
<Address PostCode="ABC">    <!-- PostCode is an attribute (has an @) -->
  <AddressID>1</AddressID>  <!-- AddressID is a child element (no @) -->
</Address>
```